# Upgrade angular-meteor project (v1.2.1) to Meteor 1.3

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

Meteor 1.3 was released today (yay). As it has builtin npm support and other goodies, I'd like to upgrade my angular-meteor project (the app is on Meteor 1.2.1).

I run

```
meteor update
```

and then (in response to instructions given in the meteor output on first run)

```
meteor npm install --save underscore jsondiffpatch angular clipboard
```

Following that, there were no errors on the server side (except for `[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised ...`

When loading the client I bumped into:

```
angular_angular.js?hash=... Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-meteor' is not available!
```

Which I can't seem to circumvent. 
I tried running:

```
meteor npm install --save angular-meteor
```

which completed successfully (confimed in package.json) yet angualr still can't find it.

So, what am I doing wrong? What's your advice regarding such an upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've released `1.3.9_1` that should solve that issue now.